# Rebuild Reporting DB in scaled environment takes moretime

Tags: experience-analytics, reporting

I have rebuilt the reporting DB in sitecore 9.1,For 60000 records it takes more than one-day,Which was not accepted by client.
Please let me the process how could I improve the performance of rebuilding reporting DB.

Answer (score 2):

On KB site is an article about analytics performance: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/224364

To resolve this issue follow next steps:

1.For Sitecore XP 9.1 Initial Release – 9.1 Update-1, download and execute the following script against your reporting and reporting.secondary databases:
[Sitecore.AnalyticsOptimization.sql](https://kb.sitecore.net/-/media/DF0F5D784AC841238711FB8845DC1747.ashx?la=en&hash=D1BD9228BFE336FEC1596CA7CA22C32E)

2.
Configure the processing agents. For more information see the following article:
https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/configure-processing-agents.html

3.
Tune interactions batch size. For more information see the following article::
https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/batch-aggregation.html